# Render Error while using React Router Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, router

I have this `App.js` file with this content:

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Main from './src/components/Main';

export default function App() {
  return <Main />;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

And the `Main.jsx` file with this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NativeRouter, Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-native';

const HomeScreen = () => (
    <View>
        <Text>Welcome to the home screen!</Text>
    </View>
);

const AboutScreen = () => (
    <View>
        <Text>Welcome to the about screen!</Text>
    </View>
);

const NotFoundScreen = () => (
    <View>
        <Text>Sorry, this page was not found.</Text>
    </View>
);

const Main = () => {
    return (
        <NativeRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={HomeScreen} />
                <Route exact path="/about" component={AboutScreen} />
                <Redirect from="/old-about" to="/about" />
                <Route component={NotFoundScreen} />
            </Switch>
        </NativeRouter>
    );
}

export default Main;
```

It's a simple example, but I experiment this error:

*Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.*

This is a screenshot with the error:

[image: Error in Expo]

Thanks in advance for your attention and help.

Comment: What's your react router version? Switch is removed in v6, you may be following the old docs. https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem today and the solution is change the Switch for Routes

```
const Main = () => {
return (
    <NativeRouter>
        <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Route exact path="/about" component={AboutScreen} />
            <Redirect from="/old-about" to="/about" />
            <Route component={NotFoundScreen} />
        </Routes>
    </NativeRouter>
);};
```